# Get public key of an EOS account name

Tags: account-name, api, public-key, apiendpoint

Most questions are asking about getting the account name from a public key. But what I'm looking for is getting the public key from an account name. How can this be done via one of the BP public api endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [get_account](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_account)